# zsh: bad math expression: operand expected at `'HTTP_HOST...'

Tags: php, zsh

I'm trying to run the following php from the terminal:

```
php -r "error_reporting(E_NONE); $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'localhost';
require('./config/site.php'); 
echo json_encode(array('HOST' => DB_SERVER, 'USER' => DB_USERNAME, 'PASS' => DB_PASSWORD, 'NAME' => DB_DATABASE));"
```

And I'm getting the following error:

`` zsh: bad math expression: operand expected at `'HTTP_HOST...' ``

Escaping the `=` has no effect and escaping the `[` gives a PHP parse error:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting identifier (T_STRING) in Command line code on line 1`

What am I doing wrong here? How can I run the code above from terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're running PHP code within double quotes, the PHP interpreter is trying to replace $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] with the value of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], to get it to work, you need to escape the $

```
php -r "error_reporting(E_NONE); \$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'localhost';
require('./config/site.php'); 
echo json_encode(array('HOST' => DB_SERVER, 'USER' => DB_USERNAME, 'PASS' => DB_PASSWORD, 'NAME' => DB_DATABASE));"
```

I did a test on one of my boxes to verify.

Without escaping

```
[root@exia ~]# php -r "var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);"
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(9) "HTTP_HOST"
}
```

With escaping

```
[root@exia ~]# php -r "var_dump(\$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);"
NULL
```

And another for good measure

```
[root@exia ~]# php -r "error_reporting(E_NONE); \$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'localhost';
var_dump(\$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);"
string(9) "localhost"
```

Comment: It's not the PHP interpreter that is trying to replace the variables, it's the shell (zsh). Expansion of shell variables happens long before the PHP binary is invoked.

Comment: It is, you can see above from the examples that it is PHP. The shell won't replace variables in a string like that.

Comment: I don't know why you believe that that the shell "won't replace variables in a string". SUS/POSIX clearly defines that double quoted blocks are to be interpreted with variable expansion enabled. Depending on the shell (the original question states it is zsh), `printf '<%s>\n' "$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']"` will either produce a math error (zsh), or `$_SERVER` will be expanded to nothing (bash, POSIX, etc). The error from PHP occurs because the data has already been expanded to a zero-length string, and PHP receives malformed syntax at invocation time.